# Multidimensional array keys to variable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, key

sadly i havent found any solution yet.

I have an multidimensional array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Symbol] => CASY.US
            [Position] => 169873920
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Symbol] => US500
            [Position] => 168037428
        ) )
```

Now i want to write the name of the keys of the inner array into variables so that i have these variables with the values:

```
$col1 = "Symbol"
$col2 = "Position"
```

How can i achieve that? Somehow with a couple of foreach loops?

Background: After that i want to check if the columns have the right name for a validation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the array look the same all the way through? Or is there a third key somewhere?

Comment: How do you plan to validate these with largely unknown variable names?  What are you validating for, you might be able to use something like `array_intersect_key` or `array_diff_key` that is better suited to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop nested and save the keys to an array with "col" and an integer that you later can (if you really must extract), but I recommend to keep them in the array.

```
foreach($array as $subarray){
    $i = 1;
    foreach($subarray as $key => $val){
        $keys["col" . $i] = $key;
        $i++;
     }
     break; // no need to keep looping if the array is uniform
}
//if you must:
extract($keys);
```

https://3v4l.org/ALVtp

---

If the subarrays are not the same then you need to loop all subarrays and see if the key has already been saved, if not save it else skip it.

```
$keys =[];
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $subarray){
    foreach($subarray as $key => $val){
        if(!in_array($key, $keys)){
            $keys["col" . $i] = $key;
            $i++;
        }
     }
}
var_dump($keys);
//if you must:
extract($keys);
var_dump($col1, $col2, $col3);
```

https://3v4l.org/EklPK

Comment: The arrays must be uniform, on the following iterations the keys just keep stacking up.  `$col1 = 'Symbol', $col2 = 'Position'`  then loop 2 `$col3 = 'Symbol', $col4 = 'Position' $col4='foo'` then loop 3 `$col6='Symbol' etc...`, so now 'Symbol' is not even odd anymore.  It will be a nightmare to check if they are not uniform.  By the time you get to the 8th iteration, you have no idea what the keys could be or what they represent.  As the answer-er  "er"  its not your fault, I just think it's a flawed approach no matter how it's done.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix No, the keys do not stack up in either of the answers. The first has a `break;` and only loops once, the second has `if(!in_array())`

Comment: @MichaelH. Feel free to accept the answer if it has been helpful for you

Comment: I missed `if(!in_array())` but it still doesn't solve the problem, as you really have no way to know what the keys will be (if they are not uniform).  So with my example `foo` is `$col3` what if I have `bar` later that's `$col4` what if the order is different next time.... they will be different numbers.  Sure it's a few what if's but you have no guarantees here.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix OP asked how to get the key names. I have no clue what OP is using it for since it's poorly mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Hence the reason I said this `As the answer-er "er" its not your fault, I just think it's a flawed approach no matter how it's done.`  -- I'm just saying ...  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would do something like this:

```
$required = array_flip(['Symbol', 'Position']); //flip because I am lazy like that ['Symbol'=>0, 'Position'=>1]
foreach($array as $subarray){
     $diff = array_diff_key($required, $subarray); 
     //prints any keys in $required that are not in $subarray
     print_r($diff);
     if(!empty($diff)){ 
          //some required keys were missed
     }
}
```

While its not clear how you validate these the reason is as I explained in this comment

> it still doesn't solve the problem, as you really have no way to know what the keys will be (if they are not uniform). So with my example `foo` is `$col3` what if I have `bar` later that's `$col4` what if the order is different next time.... they will be different numbers. Sure it's a few what if's but you have no guarantees here.

By dynamically numbering the keys, if the structure of the array ever changes you would have no idea what those dynamic variables contain, and as such no idea how to validate them.

So even if you manage to make this work, if your data ever changes you going to have to re-visit the code.

In any case if your wanting to see if each array contains the keys it needs to, what I put above would be a more sane way to do it.